# Relation between the density of the gas and ionization efficiency?

Tags: energy, charge, plasma-physics, ionization-energy

Ionization energy is defined as the energy needed to pull the electron in the outermost shell to infinity. This means that the proton is supposed to lose it's influence over the electron. Now, I know that in real life this never happens as electrons cant be at infinity. But it can be pretty far ( a few cm's is more than enough). But when we provide enough energy (ionization energy of the gas multiplied by the number of atoms), to a real gas, it turns into a plasma. Clearly, the protons didn't lose their influence over the electrons because the electron quickly comes under the influence of an other proton. So, Can I say that as the gas gets thinner and thinner, the more efficient the ionization process will be? In an other situation, where the gas exists only on a 2D surface and the applied electric field is perpendicular to the surface. Will I still find that density and ionization efficiency are inversely proportional??

Comment: What do you mean by efficient? I don't think dense gases are harder to ionise.

Comment: What I am saying is , if gasses have a lot of particles, when Ionized, electrons of an atom just come under the influence of an other atom. Hence the electron needs a lot of energy to b pulled to infiniy ( separating the plasma)

Comment: Are you then asking whether the ionisation energy is raised by an atom being in a plasma?

Comment: If the electron is energetic enough, why will it reattach to some other atom (barring some energy loss mechanism)? What is the mean free path of either a gas atom or an electron? What is the capture cross section?